# How do you publish a typescript website to GitHub Pages using Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio, github, typescript

So I made a Typescript project with Visual Studio.  It works fine when I launch it with Visual Studio, but if I try to push it to my GitHub Pages site, it will put the `index.html` in a subfolder and I get a 404 error when I try to load my website. Even if I try to reference the index.html in the website url it doesn't really work.

I was wondering if it's possible to only publish the needed items.  I think I would only need the subfolder.  Correct me if I am wrong though.

Note: I have the GitHub extension for Visual Studio installed.

[image: Project in VS]

**UPDATE:**

Since some of the links don't seem to work anymore I think I should give some extra information. So basically you need to have a branch named `gh-pages`. On that branch you need to have an `index.html` file in your **root** folder. Then the `index.html` file should be visible on the github page URL.

Comment: It would be useful if you gave some context about how you attempt to publish, showing the specific commands you run, their output etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push a branch named `gh-pages` in order to view it as a website.

Create a new branch and then move the file into the root folder of the branch, upload it to the `gh-pages` and you set to go.

Check this out:

https://github.com/nirgeier/JimVliet.github.io/tree/gh-pages

This is how your file should be inside your root folder.

[image]

Comment: Looks like that link is broken now.